# How to skip rows of csv file in BIGQUERY load API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load CSV data from cloud storage bucket to BigQuery table using BigQuery API
My Code is :

```
def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, source)
    job.sourceFormat = 'CSV'
    job.fieldDelimiter = ','
    job.skipLeadingRows = 2

    job.begin()
    job.result()  # Wait for job to complete

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
        job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))

    wait_for_job(job)
```

It is giving me error:

```
400 CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
```

this error is because,my csv file contains first two rows as header information and that is not supposed to be loaded. I have given 
job.skipLeadingRows = 2 but it is not skipping the first 2 rows.
Is there any other syntax to set skip rows ?

Please help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're spelling it wrong (using camelcase instead of underscores). It's `skip_leading_rows`, not `skipLeadingRows`. Same for `field_delimiter` and `source_format`.

Check out the Python sources [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L523).

Comment: Thanks. Yes it worked. I had figured that out but yes thanks for replying :).

Comment: I`m using Node JS @google-cloud/bigquery version 1.2.0, 
bigquery
        .dataset(datasetId)
        .table(tableId)
        .load(fileName, {skipLeadingRows: 1}) => It's works