# BigQuery loading data from bq command line tool - how to skip header rows

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a CSV data file with a header row that I am using to populate a BigQuery table:

```
$ cat dummy.csv
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
10.5,20.5,30.5,40.5
10.6,20.6,30.6,40.6
10.7,20.7,30.7,40.7
```

When using the Web UI, there is a text box where I am able to specify how many header rows to skip. However, if I upload the data into BigQuery using the `bq` command line tool, I do not have an option to do this, and always get the following error:

```
$ bq load my-project:my-dataset.dummydata dummy.csv Field1:float,Field2:float,Field3:float,Field4:float
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r7eccfe35f_0000015e3e8c_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'my-project:bqjob_r7eccfe35f_0000015e3e8c_1': CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1;
errors: 1.
Failure details:
- file-00000000: Could not parse 'Field1' as double for field Field1
(position 0) starting at location 0
```

The [bq command line tool quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-command-line#createtable) also does not mention any options for skipping headers.

One simple/obvious solution is to edit `dummy.csv` to remove the header row, but this is not an option if pointing to a CSV file on Google Cloud Storage instead of the local file `dummy.csv`.

This is possible to do through the web interface, and through the [Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262244/how-to-skip-rows-of-csv-file-in-bigquery-load-api), so it should also be possible to do with the `bq` tool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checking `bq help load` revealed a `--skip_leading_rows` option:

```
--skip_leading_rows : The number of rows at the beginning of the source file to skip.
    (an integer)
```

Also found this option in the [bq command line tool documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile) (which is **not** the same as the quickstart documentation, linked to above).

Adding a `--skip_leading_rows=1` to the `bq load` command worked like a charm.

Here is the successful command:

```
$ bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 my-project:my-dataset.dummydata dummy.csv Field1:float,Field2:float,Field3:float,Field4:float
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r43eb07bad58_0000015ecea_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
```