# How to skip header row while loading csv data in google BigQuery using client library (java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

While loading csv data to bigquery table, there is skip header row option in Web UI/python client library etc. 
[How to skip rows of csv file in BIGQUERY load API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262244/how-to-skip-rows-of-csv-file-in-bigquery-load-api)
But I cant find similar option in Java client library of BigQuery.
Currently my code is as below

```
public long writeFileToTable(String datasetName, String tableName, InputStream inStream, String location)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException,TimeoutException {
        // [START bigquery_load_from_file]
        BigQuery bigquery =BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
        WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
            WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId)               
            .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv())

            .build();
        // The location must be specified; other fields can be auto-detected.
        JobId jobId = JobId.newBuilder().setLocation(location).build();
        TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(jobId, writeChannelConfiguration);
        // Write data to writer
        try (OutputStream stream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)) {

          IOUtils.copy(inStream, stream);
        }
        // Get load job
        Job job = writer.getJob();

        job = job.waitFor();

        LoadStatistics stats = job.getStatistics();
        return stats.getOutputRows();
        // [END bigquery_load_from_file]
      }
```

But this is writing header record also in table. I was assuming that some method should be available in WriteChannelConfiguration to do this. But could not find any

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the option as below

```
WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
            WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId)               
            .setFormatOptions(CsvOptions.newBuilder().setSkipLeadingRows(1).build())                
            .build();
```